# Adjust height of container

Tags: layout, extjs

How can I achieve that my container will adjust the height accordingly of the children items when the height of the children elements is larger then configured "minHeight" of their parent element? At present the content of the div which contains the text will be cutted. Please have a look at my code.

```
con_notification = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
    id: 'con_notification',
    border: true,
    layout: {
        type:'vbox',
        align: 'center'
    },
    style: {
        zIndex: '999999'
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
con_notification.add(Ext.create('rmt.view.NotificationContainer'));
con_notification.hide();
con_notification_box = Ext.getCmp('con_notification-box');

con_notification_box.getEl().setStyle(con_notification_box_success);
con_notification_box.items.items[0].update('<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>');
con_notification_box.doLayout();
con_notification.getEl().slideIn('t', {
    easing: 'easeOut',
    duration: 1000
});

Ext.getCmp('con_application-close').getEl().on('click',function(){
    con_notification.getEl().slideOut('t', { duration: 1000 });
});
```

**rmt.view.NotificatonContainer:**

```
Ext.define('rmt.view.NotificationContainer', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    id: 'con_notification-box',
    border: true,
    width: 500,
    minHeight: 75,
        style: {
        border: '1px solid',
        borderRadius: '3px',
        padding: '15px 25px 10px 50px',
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
        backgroundPosition: '10px 4px',
        color: '#444',
        boxShadow: '0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.4) inset',
        wordBreak: 'break-all',
        wordWrap: 'break-word',
        backgroundColor: '#cfe6fc',
        backgroundImage: 'url(assets/info.png)',
        borderColor: '#a4c8f5',
        zIndex: 99999
    },
    items:[{
        xtype: 'container',
        html: '<p>Insert your information text here.</p>'
    },{
        xtype: 'container',
        id: 'con_application-close',
        cls:   'notification-close',
        html: '<img src="assets/close.png" />'
    }]
});
```

If something is unclear, don't hesitate to ask me. I'll try to explain you the unclear thing in more detail.

Thanks you very much for your support!

Answer (score 0):

OK I've never used ExjJS so I'm not familiar with the JS wrapper used BUT ... one strange foible I've encountered when doing something similar is with CSS and overflow.

Try simply setting the following in the CSS for your container div.

```
height: auto;
overflow: hidden;
```

That will, weirdly, scale the height of the container to the height of the tallest child element... even if the children are floated.